# AWSSDK S3 contantly calls http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id and fails with 404

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, aws-sdk

I am using the .Net AWSSDK to get images from S3 and in my MVC website I constantly get 404 error's reported by Application insights for the URL:
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id

How do I stop this from happening.  I know this is to get EC2 instance data but i am only talking to S3.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: And your app's not running on EC2, right?

Comment: nope, it's on Azure

Comment: What's the question - how to stop AWSSDK to make this call? Or how to configure AI SDK to stop collecting these failures because you're not interested in them?

Comment: either to stop the calls from happening, or configure it not to fail.  I can hide them in AI a few different ways but my site will still be making a ton of calls in the background which is the real issue

Answer (score 0):

This is being caused by the Stackify API we were using for logging NOT the AWS SDK